# SQL -Stored Procedure help w/1 parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

stored procedure will be named---> SP Name(usp_updateCustomerCA).

The procedure takes CustomerID as a parameter. The procedure updates the customer's state to 'CA' for corresponding customer (matched with the CustomerID).

I think the update customer state to  CA part is throwing me off.

I have this far written but not sure on the order of things

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_updateCustomerCA
@CustomerID Char(10)

AS 

SELECT
```

Comment: To do a database update you'll need to use `UPDATE`, not select. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/t_sql/t_sql_update_statement.htm

Answer (score 0):

If the procedure must update the state for a customer it would most likely look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_updateCustomerCA
@CustomerID Char(10)

AS 

UPDATE CustomerTable SET state = 'CA' where customerid = @CustomerID
GO
```

`CustomerTable` Must be the name of the table containing the field to be changed. And `state` is the field name where you are updating the value. Just Remember to change accordingly to your DB table name and state field name.